# Guidelines on backlog prioritization

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for some guidelines on backlog prioritization. We wanted to limit this activity to the Product Owner/Management team.

Is there a specific permission for that or do I need to create a team and then limit the project area permission?

I know you need to be in the [Contributor or Admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access-work-tracking) group to do it and have the correct [Access Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels), but I couldn't find any specific permission for that.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your actual issue is. Are you having trouble with the Product Owner not having the functionality you want them to have, or are you having an issue with others having functionality you DON'T want them to have?

Comment: #2. I wanted that only the PO was able to do the prioritization

Comment: That's not going to work very well from a permissions standpoint, as far as I know.

Comment: Uhm, that is what I've thought. I've seen some permissions on items creation but not on reordering/prioritization. Actually this is something that a stakeholder asked for, but I don't really think that makes total sense. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're talking about **stakeholder** in the AzDO vocabulary, that access level is not allowed to prioritize the backlog for private projects, but **IS** for public projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understand the difference between the **Stakeholder** and **Basic** *(also subscription)* user access levels, so I'm going to skip any of that explanation.

I understand you want one group of contributors to be prevented from changing the backlog and another group allowed, but those who are prevented still need to edit other parts of the work items (ie. state)

Here are the options I see for getting something like what you want:

**TL;DR** it's hard to get what you're after.

---

### Option 1

Get creative with how your process handles areas.

You could create an area node for work items to receive their priority from Product Owners and a sub node for devs to actually work on the items. This isn't pretty because now when you're loading a sprint you're not just dragging and dropping from one iteration path to another, but you're also changing the area path so that the dev group has permission to update the work items.

The way I understand this, once you move the items out of the prioritization area, devs will still be allowed to move things around (read: prioritize) on their board/backlog. However, the only work that should be in that area is the work that is planned for the upcoming or current iteration, and at that point the priority shouldn't really matter much, because it's all expected to get done by sprint end. **But** if the devs backlog has an area specification that includes the limited node, those items will still show up on the backlog with other items that are not in the limited area. The dev can still move a non-limited item above a limited item without changing the value of the stack rank on the limited item. The non-limited item finds a value that works for its new position.

---

### Option 2

Create a new project who's only purpose is to provide order to the backlog(s). Your POs will be in this project and your devs will be in the other. At sprint planning (or whatever other intake ceremony to which you subscribe) you will be pulling prioritized items from the one project into the other.

The same caveat as in option 1 applies here.

---

### Option 3

Organize your **Backlog** levels (with appropriate items) in such a way that your prioritization crew only needs to prioritize the portfolio backlog item types, and your dev crew can create/prioritize their requirement and iteration level work items as they see fit based on what their sprints look like.

The same caveat as in options 1 & 2 applies here, but at lease your devs will have more of a visual that they are operating on the wrong backlog and ought not to be messing around.

---

### Conclusion

Neither of these are the greatest options for exactly what you want, and you may find it cleaner and easier to manage the devs that are moving work items out of their priority by continually enforcing the convention and rebuking those that are not following it.